# How remove the line breaks with a tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples, strip

I want to join four files in one without the line breaks. But when I used line.strip()

```
arquivos=open("tst-temp.dat","r")
arquivo=open("cvt-temp.dat","r")
arq=open("cvtzct-temp.dat", "r")
ar=open("cvtsct-temp.dat", "r")
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open("total-anar.dat","w")
sys.stdout = f
for line in zip[arquivos,arquivo,arq,ar]: 
    print(line.strip())
f.close()
```

Python returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

If I remove line.strip(), my exiting file looks like this:

```
('#     T       TST\n', '     CVT\n', '    CVT/ZC\n', '     CVT/S\n')
('--------------------\n', '----------\n', '----------\n', '----------\n')
('100       7.30e-20\n', '7.29e-20\n', '2.17e-17\n', '6.11e-16\n')
('200       9.62e-16\n', '9.61e-16\n', '2.90e-15\n', '1.15e-14\n')
('300       2.59e-14\n', '2.59e-14\n', '4.11e-14\n', '8.09e-14\n')
('400       1.53e-13\n', '1.52e-13\n', '1.99e-13\n', '2.97e-13\n')
('500       4.94e-13\n', '4.87e-13\n', '5.83e-13\n', '7.63e-13\n')
('600       1.16e-12\n', '1.14e-12\n', '1.30e-12\n', '1.59e-12\n')
('700       2.29e-12\n', '2.23e-12\n', '2.47e-12\n', '2.87e-12\n')
('800       3.99e-12\n', '3.86e-12\n', '4.19e-12\n', '4.72e-12\n')
('900       6.38e-12\n', '6.14e-12\n', '6.56e-12\n', '7.23e-12\n')
('1000      9.59e-12\n', '9.16e-12\n', '9.69e-12\n', '1.05e-11\n')
('1100      1.37e-11\n', '1.30e-11\n', '1.37e-11\n', '1.46e-11\n')
('1200      1.89e-11\n', '1.76e-11\n', '1.82e-11\n', '1.92e-11\n')
('1300      2.53e-11\n', '2.34e-11\n', '2.39e-11\n', '2.52e-11\n')
('1400      3.30e-11\n', '3.02e-11\n', '3.08e-11\n', '3.22e-11\n')
('1500      4.19e-11\n', '3.81e-11\n', '3.87e-11\n', '4.02e-11\n')
('1600      5.25e-11\n', '4.73e-11\n', '4.72e-11\n', '4.89e-11\n')
('1700      6.46e-11\n', '5.76e-11\n', '5.74e-11\n', '5.92e-11\n')
('1800      7.82e-11\n', '6.91e-11\n', '6.81e-11\n', '7.00e-11\n')
('1900      9.36e-11\n', '8.18e-11\n', '8.05e-11\n', '8.25e-11\n')
('2000      1.11e-10\n', '9.58e-11\n', '9.42e-11\n', '9.64e-11\n')
('2500      2.24e-10\n', '1.86e-10\n', '1.83e-10\n', '1.86e-10\n')
```

I need the exit file similar to:

```
#T (K)          TST        CVT    CVT/ZCT    CVT/SCT

 100.00  7.899E-40  1.400E-40  4.342E-34  1.902E-32
 200.00  1.098E-25  5.007E-26  6.373E-25  2.474E-24
 300.00  6.550E-21  4.157E-21  1.067E-20  1.867E-20
 400.00  1.767E-18  1.327E-18  2.139E-18  2.891E-18
 500.00  5.505E-17  4.555E-17  5.899E-17  7.120E-17
 600.00  5.818E-16  5.083E-16  5.817E-16  6.614E-16
 700.00  3.302E-15  2.977E-15  3.172E-15  3.482E-15
 800.00  1.265E-14  1.161E-14  1.183E-14  1.270E-14
 900.00  3.715E-14  3.442E-14  3.410E-14  3.604E-14
1000.00  9.024E-14  8.403E-14  8.170E-14  8.541E-14
1100.00  1.904E-13  1.777E-13  1.707E-13  1.770E-13
1200.00  3.609E-13  3.361E-13  2.855E-13  2.942E-13
1300.00  6.285E-13  5.814E-13  4.971E-13  5.100E-13
1400.00  1.023E-12  9.409E-13  8.098E-13  8.278E-13
1500.00  1.576E-12  1.442E-12  1.249E-12  1.273E-12
1600.00  2.319E-12  2.113E-12  1.840E-12  1.871E-12
1700.00  3.286E-12  2.982E-12  2.610E-12  2.649E-12
1800.00  4.507E-12  4.076E-12  3.586E-12  3.633E-12
1900.00  6.012E-12  5.422E-12  4.791E-12  4.848E-12
2000.00  7.831E-12  7.043E-12  6.252E-12  6.318E-12
2500.00  2.251E-11  2.004E-11  1.812E-11  1.824E-11
```

How can I remove the line breaks?

Comment: ``for line in zip[arquivos,arquivo,arq,ar]:``
in each iteration what you receive in ``line`` is a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) , you cannot apply a strip() function on tuple.
what you can do is to join the tuple elements in one string. Replace all ``\n`` values with empty string. i.e ``str_line = " ".join(line)`` then ``print(str_line.replace('\n', ''))``

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating over the elements and constructing a new tuple from the modified values.

```py
# Assuming our tuple is called "line"

tuple(element.strip() for element in line)
```

Tuples in python are immutable. In other words, if you want to change the values in them, then you have to create a new one.

To combine with your code:

```py
arquivos=open("tst-temp.dat","r")
arquivo=open("cvt-temp.dat","r")
arq=open("cvtzct-temp.dat", "r")
ar=open("cvtsct-temp.dat", "r")
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open("total-anar.dat","w")
sys.stdout = f
for line in zip[arquivos,arquivo,arq,ar]: 
    print(tuple(element.strip() for element in line))
f.close()
```